# NodeJS / Nest logs stop showing in Google Cloud Log at specific point, locally it shows a clear change

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, nestjs, google-cloud-logging

I have the following issue. My code shows locally the following logs:

[image]

It is nest booting up, after that the log format changes and it is nodeJS console.log.

[image]

The Google Cloud log stops right after these Nest logs, as if it is logging to a different stdout? I have no idea were to look.

It seems like kubectl logs -f ... do show the logs, why not here?

Comment: You can try replacing the default Nest.js logger with dedicated GCP logger https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston

Comment: I've experienced some of the same thing, and even simple `console.log` dissapears after some time logging, so to seem them again for "some time" I need to restart the instance (the weird part is that it was "suddenly", before it worked perfectly). I don't know why but with the cloud logging package, the logs never dissapear. I even keep both, the console ones dissapears and the other ones doesn't. I created two Issues to see if someone at Google fix this (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303832784 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303736607)

Comment: I think in my case I have a problem with datadog<->cloud run integration